# Can you make a fileref that works like a libref?

Tags: sas

If you want to save datasets into a permanent library and don't want to continually retype the address, you can use `LIBNAME`:

```
LIBNAME d "C:\<file path>\My datasets"
DATA d.data1;
    ...
RUN;
```

Another feature to save typing is to use `FILENAME`:

```
FILENAME f "C:\<file path>\My datasets\data1.txt"
DATA d.data1;
    INFILE f;
    ...
RUN;
```

But this only works for one specific file, whereas `d.` can be used for any number of datasets.  Is there a convenient way to tweak `FILENAME` or a different function / PROC so that it could be used like `f.`?  For example:

```
DATA d.data1;
    INFILE f."data1.txt";
    ...
RUN;
DATA d.data2;
    INFILE f."data1.txt";
    ...
RUN;
DATA d.data3;
    INFILE f."data1.txt";
    ...
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set your path to a macro variable and then use the macro variable in your file path call

example:

```
%let path = M:\file\path;

DATA d.data1;
infile = /*include path*/ "&path.\file_name.csv"
....
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you intend to use all files with a certain pattern in a directory, is to use a fileref with a wildcard.

```
filename f "c:\temp\*.txt";
data d.data1;
infile f;
.....
run;
```

Any normal wildcard combination for your OS should work (so, "data*.txt", "data_?.txt", etc. for Windows).

Comment: How is the wildcard called in `infile f;`? Eg, what if I want `data3.text`, how does SAS know that's the one I'm after?

Comment: Wildcard only works if you want _all_ files in a directory that match a particular pattern, with the caveat that you _can_ get access to which file a record came from (ie, filename); but that is probably more cumbersome than scott's solution of using a macro variable.  So this doesn't really solve the problem of "How do I call just data3's text file"; but it solves the problem of "How do I bring in _all_ text files in the directory with a particular pattern".